# How to directly access a row at a table in PostgreSQL by using the PostgreSQL's internal library?

Tags: c, postgresql, rowid

I am writing a PostgreSQL extension using the C language. I would like to do the following tasks:

1. Store a set of rowids (or other row identifier, like ctid). Each rowid uniquely represents a row in its table.
2. Process this set and return other set of rowids
3. As a result, I want to access the tuples pointed by the returned rowids

For instance, I have a table with the rowids => {1, 2, ..., 10000}. Then, I have processed my algorithm, and as result I have the following rowids => {3, 100, 8394, 12}

However, I have some doubts:

Q1. What tuple identifier would be the best to be stored in the task 1? According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-system-columns.html), the ctid value is not recommended to be used since it can change after a VACCUM. But, which value could I store? Any recommendation?

Q2. How to directly access the set of tuples that are pointed by the returned rowids of task 2? One solution would be to use SQL query. However, is it efficient? I mean, I am writing a extension of PostgreSQL, therefore, I have access to its internal library. Is there a direct way to do it instead of use sql queries?

Comment: Instead ctid, you can use oid - see `CREATE TABLE ... WITH OID`. For extension writing, you need a postgresql source code - the internal API are not documented - low level access to tables can be done via functions: `simple_heap_insert`, `simple_heap_update`, `simple_heap_delete`. You can find examples in src/backend/commands/functioncmds.c.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Pavel. I thought to use oid, like you suggested. Regarding my second question: I would like only to retrieve the tuple and not insert/update/delete a tuple. So, I think the functions that you suggested are not able to retrieve a tuple according to the oid or other row identifier.

Comment: You have to create ScanKey, and then you should to use `heap_beginscan` and `heap_getnext` function

Comment: Via ScanKey you can find row with expected oid, but access via index probably needs much more work. On other hand, for more complex tasks, you can use SQL from extensions - see postgresql/contrib/spi

Comment: Thank you Pavel. I will use SPI.